# window.location.pathname no longer working to add/remove active states

Tags: jquery

I use a simple script to apply or remove active states on header and footer navigation links based on the user's current location, but today I noticed it's no longer working. Console doesn't produce any errors, and I haven't changed anything.

```
var current;
current = window.location.pathname;

$('ul#menu li#home-nav').addClass("active"); 

if(current.indexOf("index.php") >= 0){
    $('ul#menu li, ul#subnav li').removeClass("active"); 
    $('ul#menu li#home-nav, ul#subnav li#home-subnav').addClass("active"); 
}

if(current.indexOf("services.php") >= 0){
    $('ul#menu li, ul#subnav li').removeClass("active"); 
    $('ul#menu li#services-nav, ul#subnav li#services-subnav').addClass("active"); 
}
```

etc. Is there a better/more efficient way of accomplishing this?

Comment: Can you ensure that the IDs, and elements are intact as well? Your code seems correct.

Comment: @31piy IDs and elements are all intact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this simple solution.

```
var url = window.location.pathname;
var urlFilename = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('/')+1);

if(urlFilename !== ''){
    $('ul#menu li, ul#subnav li').removeClass('active');
    $myElm = $('ul#subnav li a[href="' + urlFilename + '"]');
    if($myElm.length){
        $myElm.parent().addClass('active');
        $myElm.parent().parent().parent().addClass('active');
    }
}
```

It would be very helpful if you share the HTML as well.

Thanks.